# tqsl - result from select query to operate as variable in subqueries?

Tags: t-sql

For each user, I want to produce an aggregate result. However, I keep running into the problem of the subquery returning more than 1 result.

```sql
SELECT **[user]**, 
   ((SELECT SUM(amount) 
          FROM transactions 
          WHERE [user] = **[user]** 
          AND [type] = 'credit' ) - 
            (SELECT SUM(amount) 
            FROM transactions 
            WHERE [user] = **[user]** 
            AND [type] = 'debit' )) 
     FROM transactions
```

How do I get the `user` from the `select` at the start to then operate as the variable `user` in the subqueries?

Comment: Thanks @sll for cleaning up the presentation of the code :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use [`CASE`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181765.aspx) to simplify the summing:

```
SELECT user,SUM(CASE type WHEN 'credit' THEN amount WHEN 'debit' THEN -amount END)
from transactions
GROUP BY user
```

If credit and debit are the only valid types, then it can be simplified further as:

```
CASE type WHEN 'credit' THEN amount ELSE -amount END
```

---

The answers using subqueries for the summing activity, whilst still selecting user from the transactions table will perform the summation multiple times - once for every row in the transactions table - so if one user has 5 transactions, they're going to compute the sums 5 times (and show 5 result rows), which I assume you do not want.

Comment: Thanks @Damien_The_Unbeliever! Previously my PHP & TSQL solution was taking over 30secs to complete... but now it has drastically reduced to under 1sec!!! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 2):

```
select username,
       SUM(amount * case when operation = 'credit' then 1 else -1 end) as balance
from #transaction
group by username
```

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
 SELECT user, 
    (SELECT SUM(amount) 
     FROM transactions 
     WHERE [user] = t.User
        AND [type] = 'credit') 
     - 
    (SELECT SUM(amount) 
     FROM transactions 
     WHERE [user] = t.User
       AND [type] = 'debit' )) 
 FROM transactions t
```

or this:

```
 SELECT user, 
    Sum (Case type When 'credit' then Amount End) credit,
    Sum (Case type When 'debit'  then Amount End) debit,
    Sum (Case type When 'credit' then Amount
                   When 'debit'  then -Amount End) NetAmount    
 FROM transactions t
 Group By User
```

Comment: Thanks Charles for your thoughts, but I opted for the slightly more succinct option :)

Answer (score 1):

I like @Rubens answer, but...

Your data structure could use some work.

Actually storing the word 'credit' or 'debit' for each transaction, let alone having to evaluate it with a case statement in order to turn it into a usable value (1 or -1) is costly.

If your transaction table keeps track of quantity, then you might be able to use that instead of storing and evaluating 'credit' and 'debit'.  Positive quantities (e.g., I bought 2 rakes, etc.); and Netagive quantities (e.g., -1 rake, which implies that you returned or got a credit for one of the rakes) can be summed without performing any case-statement evaluations.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe

```
SELECT t.user, 
((SELECT SUM(amount) FROM transactions WHERE [user] = t.user AND [type] = 'credit' ) -
(SELECT SUM(amount) FROM transactions WHERE [user] = t.user AND [type] = 'debit' )) 
FROM transactions t
```

Comment: Unfortunately @Marc this option did not work. It did not provide a single aggregate result for each user. Thanks anyway :)

Answer (score 0):

A variation on [@Rubens Farias](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6845250/tqsl-result-from-select-query-to-operate-as-variable-in-subqueries/6845378#6845378)'s solution:

```
SELECT
  t.[user],
  SUM(t.amount * x.factor)
FROM transactions t
  INNER JOIN (
    SELECT 'credit', 1 UNION ALL
    SELECT 'debit', -1
  ) x (type, factor) ON t.type = x.type
GROUP BY t.[user]
```

Comment: You need names on your columns in your subselect

Comment: @t-clausen.dk: The columns' aliases are assigned in the brackets just after the subselect's alias: `x (type, factor)`.